SwiftUI Image Not Displaying Correctly in VStack with Conditional Rendering
I'm working on an iOS app using SwiftUI, and I've encountered an issue with displaying images conditionally within a VStack. My goal is to show an image only if a certain condition is met. However, when I set up my condition, the image sometimes doesn't render even when the condition is true, or it causes the layout to shift unexpectedly.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isImageVisible: Bool = true
    @State private var imageName: String = "example_image"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Toggle Image Display")
            
            Toggle("Show Image", isOn: $isImageVisible)
                .padding()

            if isImageVisible {
                Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            } else {
                Text("Image is hidden")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

When I toggle isImageVisible, the image appears or disappears as expected, but sometimes it fails to load or displays inconsistently. Additionally, when I load larger images or toggle the state quickly, the layout shifts or doesn't update smoothly. Sometimes, I even get a blank area where the image should be.
What I've Tried:
Wrapping the Image in a Group, but it didn't change the behavior.
Using .animation(.easeInOut) on VStack to smooth the transition, but it didn't fix the issue.
Checking the asset name to ensure it’s correct – the image exists and should be rendering correctly.
Any insights or alternative approaches would be appreciated! Thank you!

hm, looks good to me, but are you sure that images input are in the same format?

Try with a default image (a blank image or anything) and Image(uiImage: imageName ?? defaultImage ?? UIImage()). Problem might be related to rendering.

Yes, I've checked the image formats, and they're all the same (e.g., PNG format). The issue occurs even with a consistent format across all images. I've also verified the asset names, and they match what's referenced in the code.

Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try using a default image as a placeholder to see if that helps stabilize the rendering. I’ll also test Image(uiImage: imageName ?? defaultImage ?? UIImage()) to handle any potential nil cases.

I couldn't reproduce the images not loading issue, but if you are having trouble with the view resizing, have you considered delegating the same frame size (particularly the height) to the text as well?
As in,
if isImageVisible {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
        } else {
            Text("Image is hidden")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
        }


I appreciate the suggestion. I'll try setting a fixed frame size for the Text view to match the Image dimensions when the image is hidden. That might indeed help with the resizing issue and keep the layout consistent. Thanks again for the idea!
